# Use of unresolved identifier FBSession

Tags: ios, facebook, swift

In my swift project, I am integrating facebook SDK using bridging File.

```
if FBSession.activeSession().state == FBSessionState.CreatedTokenLoaded{
   // whatever
}
```

I am getting the error message:

> FBSession unresolved identifier

I could not find `FBSession.h` in `FBSDKCoreKit.framework v4.0.1`

Comment: `FBSession` has been removed in the version 4.0 of the Facebook iOS SDK, take a look to the [release notes](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/change-log-4.x)

Comment: Hey hi, Tkanzakic
Then how to handle session and get current session state?

Comment: see the [upgrading guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/upgrading-4.x) and read the new login flow [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/v2.3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Naming has changed to

```
FBSDKSession
```

Answer (score 2):

Facebook SDK updated use [FBSDKAccessToken](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBSDKAccessToken/)